# Blog Image not showing in Index page of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I've added blogs(containing images) to my wordpress website. The images are showing in the blog page but not showing in the index page of blogs.

**Blogs Index Page:**
[image]

**Single Blog:**
[image]

Note: I've verified by switching the themes but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching the issue, I just found a simple solution to that problem. There is an option named "Feature image" while adding/editing a new post, all I needed to do was just add an image here and it shows up in the index page. Nothing too complicated to do.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

can you check file permission? some images will not load if there is no permission

Comment: How to check file permission? I've no idea about that.